# Alternatives to drop-shadow filter in D3 animation

Tags: javascript, animation, d3.js, maps

I created an animation using D3, featuring a world map similar to [this one](https://bl.ocks.org/tmayer/9355393). The animation consists in moving airplanes icons along some arcs, exactly as in [this article](http://www.tnoda.com/blog/2014-04-02).

Notice that the contours of the countries are highlighted with a shadow, produced with the following code:

```
var filter = svg.append("defs")
    .append("filter")
    .attr("id", "drop-shadow")
    .attr("height", "130%");
filter.append("feGaussianBlur")
    .attr("in", "SourceAlpha")
    .attr("stdDeviation", 5)
    .attr("result", "blur");

var feMerge = filter.append("feMerge");
feMerge.append("feMergeNode")
    .attr("in", "offsetBlur")
feMerge.append("feMergeNode")
    .attr("in", "SourceGraphic");

...

svg.insert("path", ".map")
    .datum(topojson.feature(countries, countries.objects.land))
    .attr("class", "land")
    .attr("d", path)
    .style("filter", "url(#drop-shadow)");
```

Unfortunately, this shadow is costing an enormous amount of performance in my animation loop (although the shadow itself is not animated):

[image: perfo benchmark]

- Is it possible to prevent the shadow to be recomputed every time? (as it is always at the same location and rendered the same way)
- Are there lighter/faster alternatives to drop-shadows which would produce a similar visual effect?

Comment: What animation loop?

Comment: @GerardoFurtado, an animation of aircraft icons along arcs, as in [this article](http://www.tnoda.com/blog/2014-04-02)

Comment: I saw that... I meant "what animation loop **in your code**". Without seeing your code it's hard to tell what you're doing wrong.